# Мне нужно чтобы здоровье у Гриффина отнималось до тех пор пока не станет равное нулю

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

```
const Witcher = {
       Whealthpoint: 1000,
       Wdefencepoint: 100,
       Wstrength: 120,
       Wweapon: 250,
   };
   const Griffin = {
       Ghealthpoint: 2000,
       Gdefencepoint: 120,
       Gstrength: 150,
       Gweapon: 0,
   };
   let damage = 250;
   let probability = Math.random();
   for (let i = 0; i = Ghealthpoint; i--){
    function hit(Griffin){
        if (probability > 0.7){
        alert('вы нанесли гриффону' + ' ' + '250' + ' ' + 'урона' + ',' + ' ' + 'у Гриффона соталось' + ' ' + '1750' + ' ' + 'HP');
   }
   else{
        alert('не попал')
   }
        
    }
   }
```

Comment: Питера Гриффина в смысле? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас немного бардак в коде, чуть чуть подправил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const Witcher = {
  Whealthpoint: 1000,
  Wdefencepoint: 100,
  Wstrength: 120,
  Wweapon: 250,
};
const Griffon = {
  Ghealthpoint: 2000,
  Gdefencepoint: 120,
  Gstrength: 150,
  Gweapon: 0,
};

let damage = 250;
function hit(griffon, chance) {
  if (chance > 0.7) {
    griffon.Ghealthpoint -= damage;
    alert(`Вы нанесли грифону ${damage} урона, у грифона осталось ${griffon.Ghealthpoint} HP`);
  } else{
    alert('Промах')
  }
}

while(Griffon.Ghealthpoint > 0) {
  let probability = Math.random();
  hit(Griffon, probability)
}

alert('Грифон убит');
```